# Ubuntu 20.04: Can't install pip for python3.10

Tags: apt, 20.04, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pip

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 TLS in Windows Terminal from on Windows 10 Pro.
Ubuntu has default version of python that is 3.8, but I need 3.10, and
I can easily install it with `sudo apt install python3.10` (before I
need add deadsnakes ppa), but this is where's problem. Then I try to
install pip using `sudo apt install python3-pip` it installs it for
just 3.8 but I need it also for 3.10. I tried using get-pip.py and
it actually installed it but then I tried it it just run into so many
problems that are very very hard to solve. So my question is how am
I supposed to install Python3.10 with Pip for it to don't break anything.
Note: I tried using aliases and update-aliases but none of them worked
for me.

Comment: Read up on python virtual environments to use python versions outside of the system version.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ pip install python3.10-venv  # install venv submodule
$ python3.10 -m venv test.env  # create new test virtual environment
$ source test.env/bin/activate # activate the environment
```

You can now use python, pip, etc within your environment:

```
(test.env) $ python --version
Python 3.10.7
(test.env) $ which python
/home/ubuntu/py310.env/bin/python
(test.env) $ which pip
/home/ubuntu/py310.env/bin/pip
```